# Let $S$ be any set with the trivial metric. Prove that if $E \subset S$ is connected, then $E$ cannot have more than one element.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be any set with the trivial metric (where $a,b \in S$, then $d(a,b)=0$ if $a=b$ and $1$ otherwise). Prove that if $E \subset S$ is connected, then $E$ cannot have more than one element.

I started thinking that if $E$ has two elements, then it obviously cannot be connected because no matter how close the elements get, the distance will be 1 because it is the trivial metric.  But I'm not sure that proves the $E$ cannot have more than one element.

Comment: Do you know that a continuous image of a connected space is connected? And that $x\mapsto d(a,x)$ is continuous? And that $\{0,1\}$ is not connected?

Answer (score 1):

Under this metric, any subset of $S$ is open (because every singleton is actually a ball). So if $E$ has at least two elements, and $x\in E$, then $E=\{x\} \cup E\backslash \{x\}$ is the union of two disjoint open, non-empty sets. By definition it is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

What you thought is true. If $a, b \in E$ with $a \neq b$ then $d(a,b)=1$ and so $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ (the balls of radius $\frac 14$, which have only one element at distance less than 1) are disjoint open sets that separate $a$ and $b $.

See that with the trivial metric, two distinct elements can't be "close" or "far", as the way one can think in a plane. The distance is always $1$. $S$ needs not be a plane, it can be any set